# Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, azure-cloud-services

I have just bought a new development machine and have taken the latest version of the source code of a project we are working on but when I try to debug it I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Business' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)
```

"Business" is a class library project in the solution so it's unusual that it cannot load this assembly.

I've spent quite a big of time this morning double checking that the assembly references in both projects are targeting the same versions and they are.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The new machine had Panda Anvirus Free version installed. Although no errors were reported by it, it was interfering with the debug session. Once it was disabled the application started to work.

Once Panda AV was uninstalled the problem was no more. Hope this helps someone else that encounters the same issue!

Comment: Adding this folder to the exclusion list of Panda AV solves the issue without having to uninstall / disable Panda in its entirety: `%TEMP%\Temporary ASP.NET Files`, e.g. `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

Comment: Yes that makes complete sense. I suppose I uninstalled because I was so frustrated with Panda AV at the time!

Comment: +1 to @AronVanAmmers for the solution.  Been finding Panda much less intrusive than AVG so glad I can keep using it. :)

Comment: Cheers :). Update on this: I had to add the development folder itself to Panda's exclusion path as well, as the issue would occur when doing things like `Add-Migration`. After that I haven't seen it anymore.