# EF Downgraded: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been getting the error below and for heavens sake I cannot figure out why. I have not made any changes except for upgrading to windows 10. I have downgraded my EF and upgraded to make sure I have the same version but that did not resolve. I have tried all options, did self host the application but even that did not help eliminating Visual Studio issues.

Would appreciate any suggestions please.

Could not load file or assembly `'EntityFramework'` or one of its dependencies. 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process
>   cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework' could not be loaded.

**=== Pre-bind state information ===**

```
> LOG: DisplayName = EntityFramework  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding
> information was supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name:
> EntityFramework | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only
> part of the assembly display name is provided. WRN: This might result
> in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to
> provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that
> consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
> WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for
> more information and common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
> file:///C:/src/prjPptsWa/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
> C:\src\prjPptsWa\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
> === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\src\prjPptsWa\web.config LOG: Using
> host configuration file:
> C:\Users\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine
> configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
> custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
> download of new URL
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
> ASP.NET Files/root/17d130d2/d3bf1590/EntityFramework.DLL. LOG:
> Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
> ASP.NET
> Files/root/17d130d2/d3bf1590/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.DLL. LOG:
> Attempting download of new URL
> file:///C:/src/prjPptsWa/bin/EntityFramework.DLL. LOG: Using
> application configuration file: C:\src\prjPptsWa\web.config LOG: Using
> host configuration file:
> C:\Users\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using machine
> configuration file from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
> LOG: Post-policy reference: EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 ERR: Failed to
> complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070020). Probing terminated.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

**Update:-** Got a fix for my issue, the fix was to remove the mapping and remap to another folder. For some reason the old folder was holding dll's from being loaded.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27EntityFramework%27&oq=Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27EntityFramework%27&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) before posting this question

Comment: I have looked at all the links

Answer (score 0):

Your EntityFramework DLL is being used by another program in your system. This is the reason you can not load this assembly in bin, when you compile. I can not tell which program is currently using this dll. Do you have Panda AV installed in your machine. If yes disable it and try if it works.

Comment: There are few similer questions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412632/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-process-canno), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890371/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxx-data-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-be)

Comment: I have deleted my EntityFramework to see if I get the messages you cannot delete the dll as it being used by another process but it got deleted. Once I rebuilt it the dll is there again. And I stopped all my Anti Virus.